# Chrome -webkit-box-flex doesn't expand in HTML5

Tags: html, google-chrome

I want to setup a simple website structure with a header, content, and footer. The header and footer are set sizes, with the content expanding to fill the extra white space. The site should also enforce a minimum size of 800x600. This works fine without a DOCTYPE specified but once I add  the content section doesn't expand.

Here's my code. Remove the DOCTYPE to see it work appropriately. This code only works for Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="min-width: 800px; min-height: 600px;margin: 0px; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-box-flex: 1.0; background-color: gray;">
    <div style="height: 50px; background-color: red;">Header</div>

    <div style="background-color: yellow; -webkit-box-flex: 1.0;">Content</div>

    <div style="height: 50px; background-color: blue;">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I cant be of any help, never even heard of -webkit-box-flex (sounds usefull) but another way you can get the same sort of layout is described here...  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/

Comment: I know how to do that layout, but its not what I'm aiming for. I don't want the Footer always visible. I always want it at the bottom, even if there is not enough content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`html` and `body` won't occupy the full viewport unless you specify it so you need to...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This will fix your problem. But I must confess I have no idea why removing the doctype achieves the same effect.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the body with height of 100%, but not the html. That fixed it.